# How to update entire JTree

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I have a function called `buildTree()` that manages to build the entire tree of folders and files of my Google Drive folder.

As each "Google Drive Entry" I have has a "Modified Timestamp" field, I want to build a dynamic tree to see the changes in that tree over time using a JSlider based on those timestamps.

For that I have another function called `buildTimedTree(timestamp)` that is supposed to create a new tree based on the timestamp that is passed as an argument and only returns the tree as  it was before that timestamp.

Each of these two functions return a `DefaultMutableTreeNode` which is suposed to be the `root` node.

The code I'm using is the following.

```
JTree tree = new JTree(drive.buildTree());
tree.setBounds(148, 30, 463, 566);
scroll = new JScrollPane(tree);
scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
scroll.setBounds(148, 30, 463, 566);
frame.getContentPane().add(scroll);

//the slider has been created before
slider.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
        JSlider source = (JSlider) e.getSource();
        Long timestamp = _table1.get(source.getValue());
        DefaultTreeModel model = (DefaultTreeModel)tree.getModel();
        model.reload(buildTimedTree(timestamp));
    }
});
```

The thing is, the UI is not updating when I run the program and move de slider.

Any opinions why?

Comment: Not a Swing expert, I’m thinking `tree.repaint();`.

Comment: First get your logic working using hard coded data to make sure you understand how to use the reload(...) method. The is load the tree with simple data. Then add a button to the frame the will reload() the tree with different hardcoded data. If it works great, then you know how to use the reload() method. If not then you have a proper [mcve] to post in the forum. Then once you get it working with hardcoded data you get if working with dynamic data.